# How to fill a table with the selected values of a Scatter Plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, callback, bokeh

I'm trying to produce a table from the selection in a scatter plot in `bokeh` in `spyder`.

Using a `ColumnDataSource` I can brush link different plots.

I would like to fill a table with the selected values.

I succeeded to get the indices for a single selection via a callback.

```
def callback(attr, old, new):
    patch_name =  source.data[new['1d']['indices'][0]]
    print(patch_name)
```

Is it possible to get the iNdices of multiple selections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new `ColumnDataSource` to build the `DataTable` and update the data of this datatable each time a selection is made:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.widgets.tables import DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.io import curdoc

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
))

p = figure(
    plot_height=300,
    tools='lasso_select'
)

rc = p.scatter(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    size=20,
    color='red',
    source=source,
    fill_alpha=1.0,
    line_alpha=1.0,
)

columns = [
    TableColumn(field="value", title="Value"),
]
init_cds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(value=['']))
table = DataTable(
    source=init_cds,
    columns=columns,
    reorderable=False,
)

def update_table(attr, old, new):
    print(new.indices)
    if new.indices != []:
        new_vals_dict = {'value': new.indices}
    else:
        new_vals_dict = {'value': ['']}
    table.source.data = new_vals_dict

source.on_change('selected', update_table)

curdoc().add_root(row(children=[p, table]))
```

**Note**: If you update to the latest Bokeh version you can use the new `Selection` objects. You only need to access to the selected indices like this: `new.indices`